# Private Message with node.js issues setting up

Tags: privatemsg, nodejs

I have followed the suggested video tutorials https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u1sxDaH3Z-U and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f8XAT1oB1eA

Im using the node.js watchdog submodule for debugging. That's what the tutorial video did. She didnt have any problems.

Any clues?

```
backendSettings = {
  "scheme":"http",
  "host":"localhost",
  "port":8989,
  "key":"/etc/nginx/ssl/SECURITY.key",
  "cert":"/etc/nginx/ssl/SECURITY.crt",
  "resource":"/socket.io",
  "publishUrl":"publish",
  "serviceKey":"",
  "backend":{
  "port":80,
  "host":"panduh420.com",
  "messagePath":"/nodejs/message"},
  "clientsCanWriteToChannels":true,
  "clientsCanWriteToClients":true,
  "extensions":"",
  "debug":false,
  "transports":["websocket",
  "polling"],
  "jsMinification":true,
  "jsEtag":true,
  "logLevel":1};
```

[image]
[image: errors]

Comment: Did you try my answer? how did it go?

Answer (score 1):

I had problems too. On line 3, for some reason using localhost never worked for me. Change line 3 to

```
"host":"panduh420.com",
```

Also, if your server has a firewall, make sure port 8989 is open.

Also, if you are not going to use https, then you don't need a key or cert.

here is mine

```
backendSettings = {
  "scheme":"http",
  "host":"mywebsite.com",
  "port":8080,
  "key":"/path/to/key/file",
  "cert":"/path/to/cert/file",
  "resource":"/socket.io",
  "publishUrl":"publish",
  "serviceKey":"",
  "backend":{
  "port":80,
  "host":"mywebsite.com",
  "messagePath":"/nodejs/message"},
  "clientsCanWriteToChannels":false,
  "clientsCanWriteToClients":false,
  "extensions":"",
  "debug":false,
  "transports":["websocket",
  "flashsocket",
  "htmlfile",
  "xhr-polling",
  "jsonp-polling"],
  "jsMinification":true,
  "jsEtag":true,
  "logLevel":1};
```

Comment: thanks for trying to help. Unfortunately that didn't work. I tried just changing the config file to panduh420.com and then i also tried changing every place in the site module configuration from localhost to panduh420.com. still nothing.